# How to reference to more than 1 layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I hope I'm explaining this correctly. Basically I have a basic Android app with navigation bar on the left, and I'm trying to make the content page change layout based on what I select there.

What I did was to include both layouts on the application main layout, but when I try selecting from the nav bar, the layouts are on top of each other.

Can I get a pointer of to make them not to lay on top of each other? Am I approaching this correctly?

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.test.justforfun.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <include layout="@layout/content_second"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Use navigation bar with Fragments and Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Show one layout one time, and show another when you select sth.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility to GONE when you need to hide the layout. And then again to VISIBLE when you want to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Fragment instead of hiding and showing layout/views. Set listeners on your Navigation Bar and use FragmentManager to replace your current fragment.

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
            fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}
```

source: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer